# Ruby on Rails + mongoid: Validator not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

```
mongo => 2.0.4
rails => 3.2.2
ruby => 1.8.7
```

I'm following a tutorial (actually a combination of some tutorials), and I have a relatively simple model and I'm working on a CRUD.  Everything I've read says to put this:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :foo
  validates :foo, presence: true
end
```

Everything was working at first, but I added the `validates` line.  I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
   validates :task, presence: true
```

I have to assume this is due to some older version of ruby.  I also tried this:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :foo
  validates :foo, presence => true
end
```

...but then I get

```
Unknown validator: 'FooValidator'
```

in my browser, but simply `Unknown validator: 'Validator'` when running `guard` (using `rspec`).  I'm not sure what the issue is, and Google has been no help.  It seems that either of the two blocks that I have should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `...:foo, presence` to `...:foo, :presence`